# how to display a weekday(set it to zero) of datepart function when there are no occurence of the day in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, datepart

Sat Naam

I have a table in my databse that register of sales and stores. some stores are close on sundays so there are no sales on that day

i have the following query code to get the number of sale

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [Data_Hora_Ficheiro_fim]),[Store_id],count([sales_no])
  FROM [GPOS].[dbo].[V_Period_stats_with_CAE_GC]
       group by [Store_id],[Store name],DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[Data_Hora_Ficheiro_fim])DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [Data_Hora_Ficheiro_fim])
  order by DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [Data_Hora_Ficheiro_fim]),DATENAME(WEEKDAY, [Data_Hora_Ficheiro_fim]),[Store_id]
```

of the query would be something like(store 4 close on sunday)

```
day         Storeid    num_sales
----------|--------|----------
Monday      3        90
Tuesday     3        70  
Wednesday   3        20
Thursday    3        60
Friday      3        96
Saturday    3        98
Sunday      3        200  
Monday      4        90
Tuesday     4        70  
Wednesday   4        20
Thursday    4        60
Friday      4        96
Saturday    4        98
```

so what changes do i need to do to my query in order to the output also include the line

```
Sunday    4        0
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to cross join the weekdays and distinct `store_id` to get all combinations of the two, and `left join` your view.

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) for the first part and a [Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql)

```
;with Weekdays as (
  select 
      day=datename(weekday, convert(datetime,t.n)) 
    , s.Store_id
  from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6)) t(n)
    cross join (
      select distinct Store_id
      from [gpos].[dbo].[V_Period_stats_with_cae_gc]
      ) s
)
select 
    w.day
  , w.[Store_id]
  , count(v.[sales_no])
from Weekdays w
  left join [gpos].[dbo].[V_Period_stats_with_cae_gc] v
    on w.day = datename(weekday, v.[Data_Hora_Ficheiro_fim])
   and w.Store_id = v.Store_id
group by 
    w.day
    w.Store_id
order by 
    w.day
  , w.Store_id
```

rextester demo (modified for provided example data): http://rextester.com/JZLF76266

returns:

```
+-----------+---------+-----------+
|    day    | storeid | num_sales |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
| Monday    |       3 |        90 |
| Tuesday   |       3 |        70 |
| Wednesday |       3 |        20 |
| Thursday  |       3 |        60 |
| Friday    |       3 |        96 |
| Saturday  |       3 |        98 |
| Sunday    |       3 |       200 |
| Monday    |       4 |        90 |
| Tuesday   |       4 |        70 |
| Wednesday |       4 |        20 |
| Thursday  |       4 |        60 |
| Friday    |       4 |        96 |
| Saturday  |       4 |        98 |
| Sunday    |       4 |         0 |
+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

---

If you have a table where `store_id` is unique (e.g. dbo.Store) then that would be an alternative source for `select distinct Store_id ...`.

Another option would be to use a calendar table restricted to the date range you are interested in cross joined with the `Store_id`. This would allow you to join on an actual `date` data type instead of the `datename()` function, which would could improve performance.

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)